# java.lang.NullPointerException React Native

Tags: android, build, react-native

I've been trying to build my React Native application for release, but I always get this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
```

Can't really understand why. It's not my first app but it's the first time I have this error. I only have this when I want to assemble the application. The development mode works fine.

Here is the Stacktrace:

```
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
Scanning folders for symlinks in /**/node_modules (17ms)
Scanning folders for symlinks in /**/node_modules (17ms)
Loading dependency graph, done.
warning: the transform cache was reset.
bundle: start
bundle: finish
bundle: Writing bundle output to: /**/android/app/build/intermediates/assets/release/index.android.bundle
bundle: Done writing bundle output
bundle: Copying 339 asset files
bundle: Done copying assets
:app:processReleaseManifest

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:210)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.toString(Joiner.java:433)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:111)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.appendTo(Joiner.java:152)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:193)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:183)
        at com.google.common.base.Joiner.join(Joiner.java:209)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask$1.apply(ManifestProcessorTask.java:98)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask$1.apply(ManifestProcessorTask.java:95)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators$8.transform(Iterators.java:799)
        at com.google.common.collect.TransformedIterator.next(TransformedIterator.java:48)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterators.addAll(Iterators.java:362)
        at com.google.common.collect.Lists.newArrayList(Lists.java:160)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toCollection(Iterables.java:337)
        at com.google.common.collect.Iterables.toArray(Iterables.java:328)
        at com.google.common.collect.Ordering.sortedCopy(Ordering.java:816)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.ManifestProcessorTask.serializeMap(ManifestProcessorTask.java:93)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests.getManifestPlaceholders(MergeManifests.java:134)
        at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.MergeManifests_Decorated.getManifestPlaceholders(Unknown Source)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo$4.create(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:457)
        at org.gradle.util.SingleMessageLogger.whileDisabled(SingleMessageLogger.java:171)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$PropertyInfo.getValue(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:455)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$Validator.validate(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:278)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:41)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:203)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:185)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:66)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:50)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:153)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:150)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:98)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:83)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:99)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:81)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:173)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:239)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:212)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:205)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:55)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)


BUILD FAILED

Total time: 2 mins 44.547 secs
```

And the debug:

```
10:24:36.276 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.276 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:compileReleaseShaders (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
10:24:36.276 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.276 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseAssets
10:24:36.276 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:generateReleaseAssets'
10:24:36.276 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter] Skipping task ':app:generateReleaseAssets' as it has no actions.
10:24:36.276 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:generateReleaseAssets'
10:24:36.276 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.277 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.001 secs.
10:24:36.277 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:mergeReleaseAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.277 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:mergeReleaseAssets
10:24:36.277 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'
10:24:36.278 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets' is up-to-date
10:24:36.286 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets' as it is up-to-date (took 0.008 secs).
10:24:36.286 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:mergeReleaseAssets'
10:24:36.286 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.286 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:mergeReleaseAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.009 secs.
10:24:36.286 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseResValues (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.286 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseResValues
10:24:36.287 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:generateReleaseResValues'
10:24:36.287 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:generateReleaseResValues' is up-to-date
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':app:generateReleaseResValues' as it is up-to-date (took 0.001 secs).
10:24:36.288 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:generateReleaseResValues'
10:24:36.288 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseResValues (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.002 secs.
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseResources (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.288 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseResources
10:24:36.288 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:generateReleaseResources'
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter] Skipping task ':app:generateReleaseResources' as it has no actions.
10:24:36.288 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:generateReleaseResources'
10:24:36.288 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:generateReleaseResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.0 secs.
10:24:36.288 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:mergeReleaseResources (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.288 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:mergeReleaseResources
10:24:36.288 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'
10:24:36.290 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' is up-to-date
10:24:36.415 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':app:mergeReleaseResources' as it is up-to-date (took 0.125 secs).
10:24:36.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:mergeReleaseResources'
10:24:36.415 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
10:24:36.415 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:mergeReleaseResources (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.127 secs.
10:24:36.415 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:36.416 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets
10:24:36.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'
10:24:36.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Determining if task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' is up-to-date
10:24:37.392 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter] Skipping task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets' as it is up-to-date (took 0.976 secs).
10:24:37.393 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'
10:24:37.393 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets UP-TO-DATE
10:24:37.393 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:bundleReleaseJsAndAssets (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.978 secs.
10:24:37.393 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:processReleaseManifest (Thread[main,5,main]) started.
10:24:37.393 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :app:processReleaseManifest
10:24:37.393 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Starting to execute task ':app:processReleaseManifest'
10:24:37.395 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':app:processReleaseManifest'
10:24:37.396 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :app:processReleaseManifest (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 0.003 secs.
10:24:37.396 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 2.38 secs, idle: 0.054 secs
10:24:37.405 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:24:37.405 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
10:24:37.405 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:24:37.405 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * What went wrong:
10:24:37.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] java.lang.NullPointerException (no error message)
10:24:37.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter]
10:24:37.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] * Try:
10:24:37.406 [ERROR] [org.gradle.BuildExceptionReporter] Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
10:24:37.406 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
10:24:37.406 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
10:24:37.406 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger]
10:24:37.406 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] Total time: 11.511 secs
10:24:37.535 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache taskArtifacts.bin (/**/android/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts/taskArtifacts.bin)
10:24:37.536 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileHashes.bin (/**/android/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts/fileHashes.bin)
10:24:37.536 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache fileSnapshots.bin (/**/android/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts/fileSnapshots.bin)
10:24:37.536 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on task history cache (/**/android/.gradle/2.14.1/taskArtifacts).
10:24:37.537 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.memcache.InMemoryCachedRepositoryFactory] In-memory dependency metadata cache closed. Repos cached: 352, cache instances: 10, modules served from cache: 9300, artifacts: 1711
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Generated Gradle JARs cache (/**.gradle/caches/2.14.1/generated-gradle-jars) was closed 0 times.
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-artifacts.bin (/**.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/module-artifacts.bin)
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache artifact-at-repository.bin (/**.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/artifact-at-repository.bin)
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-metadata.bin (/**.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/module-metadata.bin)
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.btree.BTreePersistentIndexedCache] Closing cache module-versions.bin (/**.gradle/caches/modules-2/metadata-2.16/module-versions.bin)
10:24:37.538 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultFileLockManager] Releasing lock on artifact cache (/**.gradle/caches/modules-2).
10:24:37.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 0 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.0 secs)
10:24:37.540 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.CachedStoreFactory] Resolution result cache closed. Cache reads: 0, disk reads: 44 (avg: 0.0 secs, total: 0.035 secs)
10:24:37.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.store.ResolutionResultsStoreFactory] Deleted 2 resolution results binary files in 0.003 secs
10:24:37.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess] Cache Plugin Resolution Cache (/**.gradle/caches/2.14.1/plugin-resolution) was closed 0 times.
10:24:37.541 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopping 0 compiler daemon(s).
10:24:37.541 [INFO] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.daemon.CompilerDaemonManager] Stopped 0 compiler daemon(s).
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those wondering, I'm using react-native-config (https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)
One of my env variables was missing, that's why I got this error...

Comment: How did you debug this? It seems pretty difficult to find the root cause of issues like this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I faced this issue in `"react-native": "0.66.3"`
Android Release build successfully finished, but when i am uploading the bundle to play console, 
 encountered play console warning as null pointer exemption. 
Looks like new *play console started handling void tasks differently*

I solved the warnings by adding these two lines to 
*project/android/app/build.gradlew under dependency lists*

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:18.0.1'` 
`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:18.0.1'`

[more info](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#december_16_2021)